# Trying to find a solution for zip/postcode,state and city for forms?

Tags: php, jquery

Instead of making long a long list over all postcodes,state and city for my forms. Does anybody know a solution for this in php or jquery like if I for example can do something like this:

```
postcode: 1300 < Oslo
          1300-1350 Asker
          1351-1400 Bærum
          3000-3050 Drammen
and so on and on
```

so if someone writes the postcode only, then the cityname field and statename field appears depending on the postalcode

Comment: probably no solution. but it's just a matter of setting up an array with your start/stop points, then searching through the array for an entry which "contains" your code.

Comment: You can probably get a database of postcodes from the post office. There might also be a Google API for it.

Comment: You would need a database of the postcodes somewhere. I'm not sure how/where you could get access to those, but looking into that may help.

Comment: Thank you.any reference or tutorials for such thing online?